# Nullable parameter checking

Tags: c#, parameters, nullable

Let's suppose I write public API in C#:

```
public void Method(object param) 
{
    if(param == null) 
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException("Specified 'param' can not be null");
    }

// ... other business logic
}
```

I wonder is there any guarantees that I do not need to check parameter for **null** value if I have **NOT nullable** parameter (**object? param**) as method parameter? In other words is above example's checking for **null** redundant?

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with "C#" and such. That's what the tags are for.

Comment: Aside: You might want to use the `ArgumentNullException` constructor that takes two `string` parameters: `paramName` and `message`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, reference types are always nullable. Just try it: call `Method(null);` and you will get a runtime `ArgumentNullException`, exactly where you throw it in the code. You don't get a compiler error, because null is a valid value for reference types.

For value types it's a different story. If you have a parameter of type `int`, it cannot be null. In fact, `if (i == null)` won't even be accepted by the compiler.

Answer (score 1):

If your parameter is typed to a reference type then it's always possible for `null` to be passed as a value.  Hence this check, when only considering `Method` is never redundant.

It is possible for a context specific analysis of a given method to prove `null` is never used.  For example

```
sealed class Example {
  void Method(object p) {
    ...
  }
  void Other() {
    Method("hello");
  }
}
```

In this specific context you can demonstrate that `Method` can't ever be called with a `null` value (excluding of course reflection based invocation).  But this type of determination can only be done with context specific analysis

Answer (score 0):

If this is redundant or not, can not be defined in the scope of this single method, but inside your *program* domain. Where this method used? What does it supose to do? What should happen *in the program* when it fails ?

Answering this question you will find yourself answering your own.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't redundant, because a variable of type `object` can be set to null, because it's a reference type. The type `object?` doesn't exist.